# What's the best way to deal with customers that do not know what they want?

Tags: change-management, small-projects

Currently working with a customer who keeps on requesting changes. This is preventing me from signing the project off.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you an "internal" resource or "contract" ... i.e. do you cost more per day if they keep changing their mind?

Comment: "customers that do not know what they want"... also known as "customers" :)

Comment: You need to provide more context or this will be closed for being far too broad.  Can you tell us the circumstances - what is the product/technology, who are the customers, how long has the project been running etc.  Without context then answers can vary from "Build 3 prototypes and tell them to choose one" all the way to "Deny all requests for change.  Done."

Answer (score 1):

I assume from the tone of your question that you get paid for finished projects rather than per day worked.

In this case you have to be very clear about what you agreed to deliver. Usualy you would have a contract which specified extra charges for changes to this specification.

I'm assuming again, that this is not the case and you have a vague contract which basicaly says keep the customer happy but also finish asap.

I would try a number of different ways of saying no.

1. *Suck teeth* ooooo I think we would have to look at charging you extra for that. (If they agree, start a phase 2 contract)
2. Maybe we can move that into phase 2? (Phase 2 can be all their dreams, you can charge them extra)
3. I will asks the devs to investigate and see if that is possible. (Its is not. You don't understand the reason yourself)
4. Which bits do you feel you can sign off on as is? (Great, lets never talk about those bits again)
5. Let's make a list of the changes required before sign off (this list is now the spec)

Comment: Regarding number 1 and 2; that only applies in a fixed scope fixed duration project.  It won't pass muster in an agile environment since the customer is entitled to change their mind.  They can change their mind as often as they like; it's their money.

Comment: See my assumptions as to why there is a problem at all

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to handle the situation

1. Customer Engagement - This is highly important to set right expectations on the operating model that you follow to deliver a product. This operating model should include 'Project Delivery Process', 'Process to handle Change Requests', 'Process to handle Risks' and all related phases that are required for your project.
2. Business Case - Usually there will be a Business case for each requirement given by customers . You can check with your customer if there is a change to Business Case and accordingly can suggest/discuss feasible enhancements that best suits to new Business Case.
3. Manage by Control - Ensure you have controlling stages at each and every phase of your process
4. Sign off From Customers - Ensure you receive sign off from customer for respective phases as per your operating model

I would be able to provide more approaches based on your project demand, customer engagement, scope of project, etc..
Please feel to provide more details in case you need additional information.

Best.